# Functional equations and finding isomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-equations, group-isomorphism

While trying to prove that two groups are isomorphic I noticed how similar the problem is to finding a solution to a functional equation and then proving that the function is bijective. For instance in the following problem:

> Prove that $\mathbb{R^{+}(\cdot)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}(+)$

We need to find a bijective function such that $f(x \cdot y)=f(x)+f(y)$. One such function is $f(x)=\log(x)$ because of the property $\log(x \cdot y) = \log(x)+\log(y)$. Now I've had some experience with functional equations but it's very little.

**Is there a way to transform every problem that involves finding an isomorphism between groups to solving a functional equation?**

In the example I mentioned I believe it is possible but in many cases there is very little information about the operation defined on the group.

Comment: I think "yes" only in the broadest (and not particularly useful) sense - the fact that the morphism maps the group operations one to the other is a "functional equation".

Comment: I was thinking more of " Can some of these problems be solved easier if one has knowledge of solving functional equations?". Because I don't really see a general approach of how to figure out which function satisfies that relation between the operations. However a lot of the usual functional equations can be solved with certain methods like substitution etc.

Comment: Often "some of these problems can be solved easier" if one has some group theory available. It is not so much on functional equations in this area, but more on group theory. An easy example. If we have two groups of order $2017$, then they must be isomorphic. We need not find an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: This is not the point of the question. One can solve a lot of problems easily with enough knowledge obviously. I'm just trying to connect these two topics to each other.

Comment: So how would you connect finding isomorphisms between, say, finite groups and functional equations? I would not think this is a useful question. Not even for infinite groups in general.

Comment: I already mentioned I lack theory in both of these topics. This question is purely a product of my curiosity. I don't see why a question must be considered useful to be posted. That being said you probably have a good point.